# BoundingSphere intersection

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

my question should be simple (even if I can't find a way out).

When two `BoundingSphere` intersects they should share one or two points. I wanna know if there is any chance to know those points exactly (or approximately) or not.

I was thinking something like this:

- -check if the spheres intersect
- -calculate `radius_1` distance from `center_1` in the direction of `center_2`
- -calculate `radius_2` distance from `center_2` in the direction of `center_1`
- -substract the smaller to the larger and have that one as "collision" point

but since this sounds to me a little too tricky, I wanted to know if there is a simplier way to achieve this.

Hope to have made myself clear

Comment: "Simple" math - explained [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the same question on gamedev I got [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/68821/how-can-i-compute-the-common-points-when-spheres-intersect) answer.
It seems quite complete and it allowed me to understand things better and solve my problem.